# How to view next page of Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I must be blind, but I can't figure out how to view the next page of "Everything Else" mails in Gmail.

[image: Gmail]

How can I view 11-20, and so on?

Comment: Have you tried clicking **1-10 of 21,856**?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Yes, actually it shows the next 50 or so, but then I run into the same problem again. I phrased the question so the screenshot would fit on here. The email I'm looking for is sometime after all of this.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Doh, I can paginate after doing that.

Comment: I've gone through this probably five times over the last couple of years, and somehow always manage to forget exactly what to do.  This is the first time I was so impatient that I simply Googled the dilemma and found this post.  IMHO this is a terrible setup for navigation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On the far right of the header section, at the opposite of "Everything Else" will be an item count. It will show something similar to:

> 1-50 of 8580

You can click on that to then bring up a new view which will give you Previous and Next buttons for you to paginate through the rest of your email messages.

[image: previous and next buttons after showing more]

You may also notice a down arrow next to that count, which allows you to "Show more messages" and even how many messages to show at a time on screen.

[image: drop down next to count of total emails]

Comment: I'm adding another answer because I felt uncomfortable altering your answer too much. If you would like to incorporate the graphic below into your answer, I can delete it. Otherwise, I'll make it a community wiki - your choice.

Comment: Mad skillz, man!

Comment: Those buttons do exist. Even if, like on mine - the buttons are completely invisible, hidden by the background. Total pants, Google.

Comment: worst UI ever...

Answer (score 1):

***Please upvote the other answer.***

Here is a clear graphic of what you should expect to happen upon clicking -

[image]

As shown, the entire screen-view will change and the page indicators will be at the top, not the bottom.

Comment: Your votes are wasted on this answer; please don't waste them. This will either be deleted or converted to a wiki, depending on Eight's preference.